# Python: os.path.isfile won't recognise files beginning with a number

Tags: python, operating-system

So, I'm trying to incorporate `os.path.isfile` or `os.path.exists` into my code with success in finding certain regular files(pdf,png) when searching for filenames that begin with a letter.

The file naming standard that I'm using (and can't change due to the user) starts with a number and subsequently can't be found using the same method.  Is there a way that I can make these files discoverable by `.isfile` or `.exists`?

The files I'm searching for are .txt files.

```
    os.path.isfile("D:\Users\spx9gs\Project Work\Data\21022013AA.txt")

    os.path.isfile("D:\Users\spx9gs\Project Work\Data\AA21022013.txt")
```

Returns:

False

True

Comment: This definitely does work for me. Both `os.path.exists` and `os.path.isfile` recognize files that start with a number.

Comment: Nope, `isfile()` works for me on filenames that start with a number. Platform and testcase please?

Comment: `os.path.isfile()` works fine for me on a file called 01.txt

Comment: For me also its working fine. Im using python2.7.

Answer (score 16):

You need to use raw strings, or escape your backslashes. In the filename:

```
"D:\Users\spx9gs\Project Work\Data\21022013AA.txt"
```

the `\210` will be interpreted as an octal escape code so you won't get the correct filename.

Either of these will work:

```
r"D:\Users\spx9gs\Project Work\Data\21022013AA.txt"
"D:\\Users\\spx9gs\\Project Work\\Data\\21022013AA.txt"
```

Comment: Or, 3rd option: you can use a forward slash as path separator.